# Is there any way of avoiding this block of code?

Tags: java

I am remaking minesweeper for practice, and wrote this bit of code to avoid IndexOutOfBounds errors. Is there a way of avoiding this so I don't have to explicitly write out an if statement every possible error? I thought of making each array 2 indexes larger, and just ignoring the first and last index. Am I missing something obvious?

```
        if (row > 0 && col > 0)
            ray[row - 1][col - 1] += 1;
        if (row > 0)
            ray[row - 1][col] += 1;
        if (row > 0 && col < height - 1)
            ray[row - 1][col + 1] += 1;
        if (col > 0)
            ray[row][col - 1] += 1;
        if (col < height - 1)
            ray[row][col + 1] += 1;
        if (row < width - 1 && col > 0)
            ray[row + 1][col - 1] += 1;
        if (row < width - 1)
            ray[row + 1][col] += 1;
        if (row < width - 1 && col < height - 1)
            ray[row + 1][col + 1] += 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a loop instead and define the bounds once. Something like:

```
int startRow = max(row - 1, 0);
int endRow = min(row + 1, width - 1);

int startCol = max(col - 1, 0);
int endCol = min(col + 1, height - 1);

for (int r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++)
   for (int c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++)
       if (r != row || c != col) //it looks like you want to skip this cell
           ray[r][c] += 1;
```

---

Alternatively, if the operation is reversible (as in this code, you are adding 1), you can simply reverse the operation for the middle cell after the loop. This would be more efficient since it eliminates (at most) 12 comparisons, provided the operation itself were simple:

```
int startRow = max(row - 1, 0);
int endRow = min(row + 1, width - 1);

int startCol = max(col - 1, 0);
int endCol = min(col + 1, height - 1);

for (int r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++)
   for (int c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++)
       ray[r][c] += 1;

//reverse the operation for the middle cell
ray[row][col] -= 1;
```

Comment: Something seems a bit off.  Why would you want to start at 2 if `row = 3`?

Comment: cool. also, using min/max would be more clear `startRow=max(0,row-1)`

Comment: @Makoto The code in the question is walking around all of `ray[row][col]`'s neighbors. So if `row = 3`, we want to check all cells from row 2 to row 4, if they exist.

Comment: This is a nice solution. Rather than skipping the middle cell, it might be more efficient to just include it (eliminating the `if` from the inner loop) and then subtract 1 after the loops exit to correct.

Comment: @TedHopp Agreed. I did it this way because I'm *guessing* in the end the OP wants to do more with those cells than a simple reversible operation. I might be reading into the question a bit too much though. Added this to the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code a bit by using nested `if` statements. (For instance, you wouldn't need to check that `row > 0` more than once.)

However, I'd go with making the array 2 larger n each dimension, let `row` vary from `1` through `height` and `col` vary from `1` through `width`, and ignore what happens at the edges.

In your code, you seem to be pairing `row` with `width` and `col` with `height`, which seems backwards to me.

Comment: well, row and width are both horizontal, and the other two are both vertical. Felt  more natural. Didn't think of grouping row>0 though. Thanks!

Comment: @elodin - I see your point, I guess. However, I think of the `row` variable as indexing the row; and since rows stack on top of one another, `height` simply defines how many rows there are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done with for loop

```
for(int r=row-1; r<=row+1; r++)
 for(int c=col-1; c<=col+1; c++)
   if( r>=0 && r<ROWS && c>=0 && c<COLS && !(r==row && c==col) )
      ray[r][c]++;
```